# How to make square images in collectionview

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Please help.I try to make square images but I can not to do it and do not understand why(

```
     <CollectionView   ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"      
              SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
          />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image   Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                            <Label  Text="Eiffel" TextColor="Red" FontFamily="Roboto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                              </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

What I want

[image]

What I have

[image]

Please help me to make them square

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/xamformsimageresize/ ?

Comment: if the source image is not square, do you want to crop it, or squish it, or letterbox it, or what?  Have you tried setting the width and height of the image control?  Or editing the source images to be square?

Comment: I tried to assign Height and Width of the image,but it doesn't work.I want to make a square image,if the source image is not square let crop it,but make square

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the aspect of the image:

```
<Image   Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) to do that. Add the following NuGet packages to every project in your solution.

```
Xamarin.FFImageLoading

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms

Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations (if you’ll use transformations like CircleTransformation)
```

Set the `WidthRequest`and  `HeightRequest`to the same value.
Use following code to achieve it

```
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "test2.jpg">

            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                <fftransformations:CornersTransformation  CornersTransformType="AllRounded" BottomLeftCornerSize="8" BottomRightCornerSize="8" TopLeftCornerSize="8" TopRightCornerSize="8"/>
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

**My test image:**

[image]

**Here is code running result**

[image]

Comment: @Masha0307 Are there any update for this issue?  If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue